# What's the impact of TOAST on performance? (adding a hundred varchar columns)

Tags: postgresql, database-design, compression

Consider a table with the following data:

- `id`          bigint Auto Increment
- `name`        character varying(255) NULL
- `category`    character varying(255) NULL
- `english` character varying(255) NULL
- `french`  character varying(255) NULL
- `pivot`   character varying(255) NULL
- `credits` character varying(255) NULL
- `hash`    character varying(20) NULL

The `english` column contains data of the following size (in bytes): max 116, min 5, average 42, median: 40.
The number of rows in the table is around 30,000 and will hardly change.
The new 107 columns will be translations of the English.

**Will adding 107 columns hurt performance?**

The Postgres site says the maximum number of columns on a Postgres table is

> 250-1600 depending on column types

and

> The maximum number of columns for a table is further reduced as the tuple being stored must fit in a single 8192-byte heap page

Will the data fall under that limit?

## Size of the largest row

What is the *actual* storage size of the table's rows? [pg_column_size](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE) is the

> Number of bytes used to store a particular value (possibly compressed)

```sql
SELECT id, pg_column_size(t.*) FROM table as t ORDER BY pg_column_size DESC

-- Some stats derived from the query:
-- Min 87 bytes
-- Max 514 bytes
-- Average 216 bytes
-- Median: 209 bytes
```

But no compression is actually happening here, [because](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/TOAST):

> When a row that is to be stored is "too wide" (the threshold for that is 2KB by default), the TOAST mechanism first attempts to compress any wide field values. If that isn't enough to get the row under 2KB, it breaks up the wide field values into chunks that get stored in the associated TOAST table. Each original field value is replaced by a small pointer that shows where to find this "out of line" data in the TOAST table. TOAST will attempt to squeeze the user-table row down to 2KB in this way, but as long as it can get below 8KB, that's good enough and the row can be stored successfully.

Compression would start to kick in once the table gets bigger and those new columns are added.

It's unclear to me **what the compression ratio would be for such data?**

I wonder how effective it'll be on lots of short multilingual sentences. Also, tried to find the exact *name of the compression algorithm* used by Postgres: the docs say "the LZ family of compression techniques", but which one – LZ77? LZ78? A twist on one of them?

The best way to find out how much compression will achieve here is certainly to try… once I've got the translations. But I'd rather get an idea of it beforehand, as I won't get all the data at once.

## TOAST'ed?

If the size of the table goes beyond the page size limit, then Posgres will rely on TOAST not just to compress but also to split the data for "out-of-line" rows.

I understand this will increase fetch times for those rows that don't fit… But **what's the impact of TOAST on performance? Is it negligible for such a use case?**

## Bottom-line

At the end of the day…

- **Is adding those 107 columns a good idea, or should I use a different approach?**
- **If fine, how important is it to be fetching only those columns the user needs? (No user will need all of them.)**

Or am I approaching this the wrong way, i.e. is it a case of premature optimization where I'd have been better off just adding the columns and only investigate later if faced with problems?

---

*Using Postgres 9.6. Upgrading is an option if needed.*

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this falls under "premature optimization" so much as falling under poor design.  In one way or another you will need some method of know which of the 108 versions you need. But what happens when you need to add the 108th translation, or you delete say the 93rd. So use this information to form a key to a translation table. Something like Translation_Test (for_ref_in bigint, language text, translation text).  Then access the necessary text (including perhaps the English version) from that table.

Comment: I don't see your point. We need all 108 version. If ever a language is no longer needed, we can delete its column; if a new one is needed, add one. Are you suggesting to keep all translations in one table? To create 107 tables?

Comment: No I'm suggesting normalize your data. 1 table in sort of a key-value where key being table ref, language,text. for example: (1,'English','Good Morning"), (1, 'German",'Guten Morgen'), (1,Japanese,'おはようございます')  each as a separate row.

Answer (score 1):

> The best way to find out how much compression will achieve here is certainly to try… once I've got the translations. But I'd rather get an idea of it beforehand, as I won't get all the data at once.

I'd just copy the English version into each of the 107 columns.  That should be good enough to get some useful findings. You might worry that the repetition would cause the compression to be idiosyncratic; but each value is compressed in isolation so won't "know" it is identical to some other value.

> It's unclear to me what the compression ratio would be for such data?

Not very much.  For example, the paragraph of yours I quoted first doesn't get any benefit from compression (when I copied it into 107 other columns).  Short segments of ordinary text do not have enough repetition in them to be very compressible.  Translating them to other languages is unlikely to change this.

> If fine, how important is it to be fetching only those columns the user needs? (No user will need all of them.)

This question has a very clear answer.  You should absolutely select only what you need.  Assembling a row from 100+ toasted columns, just to throw most of them away, will slow you down.